# insert data with raw sql throw syntax error at or near "$1" error

Tags: knex.js

Here is my code:

```js
import { knex } from '../db-local';

async function createUserRaw(user) {
  const cols = Object.keys(user);
  const values = cols.map(col => user[col]);
  const sql = `
    insert into users (${cols.map(_ => '?').join(',')})
    values
      (${values.map(_ => '?').join(',')})
    on conflict do nothing;
  `;

  return knex.raw(sql, cols.concat(values));
}

export { createUserRaw };
```

When I try to create a user:

```js
const user = { user_id: 4, user_name: faker.name.findName() };
```

got this error:

> error: syntax error at or near "$1"

Here is the debug message from `knex.js`:

```
{ method: 'raw',
      sql: '\n    insert into users (?,?)\n    values\n      (?,?)\n  ',
      bindings: [ 'user_id', 'user_name', 4, 'Margaret Daniel' ],
      options: {},
      __knexQueryUid: '75603cf6-3ea1-4481-8412-ed3f707c5a60' }
```

I don't know where is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value bindings `?` cannot be used to pass column names (at least with postgresql). You need to use `??` binding to pass identifiers, which adds correct quotes around identifiers.

```
insert into users (${cols.map(_ => '?').join(',')})
```

Should be:

```
insert into users (${cols.map(_ => '??').join(',')})
```

and then your generated SQL will change to:

```
{ method: 'raw',
      sql: '\n    insert into users ("user_id", "user_name")\n    values\n      (?,?)\n  ',
      bindings: [ 4, 'Margaret Daniel' ],
      ...}
```

Which is valid SQL